# Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Please help Me
error Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined in angular js

```
myApp.controller('helpcontoller', ['$scope','$element','$log',
function ($scope, $element, $log, $attr, str) {
 var myElements = $( ".helppageurl" );
 for(i = 0; myElements.length>0; i++){
     var gethref = $(myElements[i]).attr('src');
     var res = gethref.substring(5);
     myElements[i].setAttribute('src', res); 

 }
 }
 ]);
```

Comment: Your `$(myElements[i]).attr('src')` code must be returning undefined and you are using `substring` method on that which gives you the error. Please debug at that line and check why it is not returning the value. Also correct your loop condition to `myElements.length>i;`

Comment: can you please provide more code or plunker?

Comment: My issue is slow